Effectively calculate horizontal pair avgs in a stream of int16's
Given a series of a pair of int16_ts. First item in each pair is left sound channel sample, second - is right. I want to make them mono: mono = (left + right) / 2 and don't want to lose even the least bit.
The following program does what I want (I am pretty sure):
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

#include <x86intrin.h>

int main()
{
    constexpr auto step = sizeof(__m128i) / sizeof(uint16_t);
    alignas(__m128i) uint16_t input[4 * step];
    uint16_t i = 0;
    for (uint16_t & x : input) {
        x = 1 + 2 * i++;
    }
    alignas(__m256i) uint16_t result[std::extent_v<decltype(input)> / 2];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::extent_v<decltype(input)>; i += 4 * step) {
        __m256 vec0 = _mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(_mm_load_si128((const __m128i *)(input + i + 0 * step)));
        __m256 vec1 = _mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(_mm_load_si128((const __m128i *)(input + i + 1 * step)));
        __m256i sum01 = _mm256_hadd_epi32(vec0, vec1);
        __m256i mean01 = _mm256_srai_epi32(_mm256_permute4x64_epi64(sum01, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0)), 1);

        __m256 vec2 = _mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(_mm_load_si128((const __m128i *)(input + i + 2 * step)));
        __m256 vec3 = _mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(_mm_load_si128((const __m128i *)(input + i + 3 * step)));
        __m256i sum23 = _mm256_hadd_epi32(vec2, vec3);
        __m256i mean23 = _mm256_srai_epi32(_mm256_permute4x64_epi64(sum23, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0)), 1);

        _mm256_store_si256((__m256i *)(result + i / 2), _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(_mm256_packs_epi32(mean01, mean23), _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0)));
    }
    fmt::println("{}", fmt::join(result, ", "));
}

But code generated by clang from trunk (for -mavx2) seems too overloaded by movs: https://godbolt.org/z/cc9v1846n
Is it normal and is it not affecting performance notably? How much improvement of performance can I expect to get if I rewrite it into e.g. inline assembly with manual register's management?

Your link is compiled with no optimizations.  Add a -O2 or -O3 flag to enable optimizations.  Of course, if you add -O3 you may find that the compiler will do all that vectorization for you (OK, it's not exactly the same, but close).

I don't know if all those shuffles are really necessary, but one thought I had was to right shift both arguments by 1 bit, calculate the 16 bit sum and add one if the original arguments were both odd. Then you could do twice as many in one go.

@SimonGoater I need that last bit

First of all, you need to compile with optimization enabled, otherwise the compiler-generated asm is a total disaster, especially with intrinsics which are inline wrapper functions for builtins that need optimization to have their args and return value variables optimized away even after force_inline.

You could use
pmaddwd (_mm256_madd_epi16) with a constant multiplier of set1_epi16(1) to get 32-bit sums of horizontal pairs with a single uop, instead of with 2 converts and a 3-uop hadd instruction (2 shuffles plus a vertical add uop: https://uops.info/)
That gives you the __m256i sum01 variable from your version (from one 256-bit load and _mm256_madd_epi16(v, _mm256_set1_epi16(1)), except with the elements in order, instead of the in-lane behaviour of 256-bit hadd.  So packing it back down to 16-bit elements after shifting can't just use vpackssdw.

Another alternative:
pavgw works vertically, but you can probably build 2 inputs for it with less work than what this requires to widen and shuffle.  But _mm256_avg_epu16 works on unsigned 16-bit integers and you need signed, You could range-shift to unsigned by XORing with 0x8000 (i.e. subtracting INT16_MIN) and then doing the same thing on the unsigned average to shift it back.
pavgw does (x + y + 1) >> 1 to be more like round to nearest instead of truncation in the division by 2.

Depending on what you need / want, I'm not sure which of vpmaddwd or vpavgw would end up being more efficient; the trick would be in optimizing the lane-crossing shuffles before and/or after.

I was unable to implement pavgw case. But pmaddwd looks pretty: https://godbolt.org/z/589e4EG45

@TomilovAnatoliy: Yeah that looks good.  Just one vpermq per vpackssdw of two vpmaddwd / vpsrad results.  Especially if you want rounding towards -Infinity like you're getting from the arithmetic right shift without vpaddd, it's probably hard to beat that with vpavgw since CPUs have efficient support for the madd.

Unfortunate that clang uses an indexed addressing mode, though, since vpmaddwd could otherwise micro-fuse into a single load+madd uop on Intel. (Micro fusion and addressing modes / https://uops.info/)
